# How do I take a screenshot in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

With WoW you can just hit print screen and it saves and image automatically but in SC2 it doesn't seem to work or maybe I just can't find the files.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Press the key on your keyboard labeled <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>

Starcraft will automatically take a screenshot and put it in your user directory.

On windows this directory can be found by going to `C:\Users\<Your Username Here>\Documents\StarCraft II\Accounts\<User Number>\<Account Number>\Screenshots`

Comment: @tzenes I knew it had to be doing something!  Thanks, I just couldn't find them.

Comment: @Kel If you didn't know, that button usually takes a screenshot and saves it to your clipboard.  You can then past it with control-v.  However, Starcraft overrides that binding to take a screenshot and automatically save it.

Comment: Does this work at any time when using the client (like menus, cutscenes etc?) Or is it an in-game only feature?

Comment: Thanks tzenes! I can't stand the lossy jpeg format though. So i messed around a bit and found that you can set the screenshot format to tga by adding this line to `Variables.txt`:
`screenshotFormat=tga`

Comment: Just for completeness sake: It's `F13` on Mac OS X

Comment: What of keyboard that don't have F13? Does CMD + Shift + 4 work?

Comment: @Kyle Yes, the printscreen functionality in Starcraft II will take and save a screenshot even in the menus, during Single Player, etc