# Where do screenshots go?

Tags: diablo-iii

I want to ask a question about an enchanted item I've found, but I can't seem to find where Diablo III saves it's screenshots by default. Where do they go?

Comment: I guess it works [like with Starcraft 2](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/how-do-i-take-a-screenshot-in-starcraft-2): C:\Users\<Your Username Here>\Documents\Diablo 3\Accounts\<Account Number>\<Some key>\Screenshots

Comment: @Anto Post as answer

Comment: Didn't want to, because I have no way to verify it right now.  But...  Sir yes sir.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I take a screenshot?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66509/how-do-i-take-a-screenshot)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For Windows users: `C:\Users\<Your Username Here>\Documents\Diablo III\Screenshots`

For Mac users: `<Your Username Here>/Library/Application Support/Blizzard/Diablo III/Screenshots` (caution: [it's a hidden folder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/69701/15726))

Comment: Presumably you meant `My Documents` on Windows. The path you quote is the default on Windows Vista. On Windows XP you'd expect it to start with `C:\Documents and Settings\...`

Comment: playonlinux: `~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/DiabloIII/dosdevices/c:/users/<our Username Here>/My Documents/Diablo III/Screenshots`

Answer (score 3):

On my system it's C:\Users\**username**\Documents\Diablo III\Screenshots.  So presumably it's under the Documents\Diablo III\Screenshots or the appropriate variant on all Windows systems.

Comment: upvote for posting it so others see, but Anto will get the check if he actually posts within an hour. He mentioned it first. :)