# How do I take a screenshot?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've tried using print screen, but it seems to grab the window behind Diablo rather than the game.  Is there some in-game hotkey to take a screenshot, or some other method that will work?

Comment: One option is to add Diablo III as a non-Steam game, then open the overlay to take a screenshot.

Comment: You are running windows or mac? (I believe that it's windows, but just to make sure)

Comment: @Michel Windows.  Looks like Nick solved the mystery.

Comment: @bwarner Yeap, but just to make the question more complete (I run in a Mac and is kind useless for me the windows information)

Comment: @MichelAyres there's no similar counterpart (`some-sort-of-Documents/Diablo III` folder) on a Mac?

Comment: @NickT I need to check. (without a mac atm)

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66318/where-do-screenshots-go

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>.  The screenshots are **automatically saved as JPGs** in your `[User]\Documents\Diablo III\Screenshots` folder.  You can rebind this shortcut in settings as LessPop and Augustus note.

You do not need to paste an image into a graphics program (e.g. Paint) and save that, if you do, you will get nothing/garbage as you note.

Comment: Oh, I never thought to look for them in a specific folder.

Comment: You can also change the key in the games settings. I have it bound to backslash because laptop keyboard.

Comment: I did mine to F12 to match Steam's.

Answer (score 2):

Mac Users can use <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>. It will save to your desktop as a .png file named with the current date and time.

Answer (score 1):

Are you in windowed mode and something may be interfering?  The proper way of taking a screenshot in Diablo III is the Print Screen button, which I've used successfully already.

Comment: I'm using fullscreen mode.  I tried both just hitting Print Screen, and Ctrl+Print Screen, but they both just gave me the browser that was also running at the time.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check your key bindings in the options mine wasn't set for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

There's always [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com). The free version only takes BMP though.