# How can I take a screenshot?

Tags: dead-space-3

I'm looking for an in-game keystroke for taking a screenshot. I Googled it, it but to no avail. I'm a bit puzzled; I tried all function keys and Print Screen but they did not help.

Comment: Print Screen didn't work?  Are you sure it didn't save a screenshot somewhere?

Comment: You could always try "Print Screen", open up paint and just paste in there.

Comment: Did you think to look in the keyboard mapping options to look for the screenshot key?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I take a screenshot?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66509/how-do-i-take-a-screenshot)

Comment: How is a Dead Space 3 question a duplicate of a Diablo 3 question?

Comment: What actually makes you think the game provides such an option? Just curious.

Comment: @murgatroid99 The answer in the linked question isn't game-specific. At least, I think that's where he was going with the duplication.

Comment: I see that, but the problem is that that means that this question is only a duplicate if the answer to it is "no, there is no keybinding to take a screenshot". Closing as a duplicate based on that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Most games (and most EA games for that matter) provide that option. But I did not find any in the settings.

Comment: Just because both games have 3 in their name does not mean that this question is a duplicate.

Comment: @whomever downvoted: care to explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any keybindings for it either, however you can never go wrong using ***[Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/)*** for your game screenshots. It'll work with any thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a GTX660 and higher, you can record with ShadowPlay. Then using VLC, you can take snapshots.

Comment: Try to give solutions that apply to a general audience or perhaps specifically to the person who asked the question.  Approximately half of all PC gamers use NVidia cards, but of that portion only some of them have a GTX660 or higher, and you have no idea if the asker is one of them.