# Where are screenshots stored on Mac OS X?

Tags: diablo-iii, macos

I know [how to take a screenshot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66509/how-do-i-take-a-screenshot). I Rebound the hotkey, and have been snapping away -  or so I thought.

I just went to look for my screenshots, and I can't find them. Not in Documents. Not in the Diablo 3 Application Folder, not in Pictures...

**Where does the *Mac* version of D3 store my screenshots?**

Comment: I think this is an appropriate use of the platform tag, as per your own suggestions on the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Krazer notes in his answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/66695/3129), Screenshots are stored in `~/Library/Application Support/Blizzard/Diablo III/Screenshots`. Unfortunately, this folder is **hidden** by default under OS X 10.7 Lion. This means that most users will have *no clue how to access their screenshots*.

There are three solutions to this.

The absolute simplest, but least persistent, is to, from the Finders **Go** menu, select `Go To Folder...`, and type in the full path: `~/Library/Application Support/Blizzard/Diablo III/Screenshots`.

If you'd like to have a desktop shortcut to your screenshots for frequent access, while still leaving the Library folder hidden, you can enter the following two commands in Terminal. This will create an alias on your desktop, which will link directly to your Diablo III Screenshots folder:

```
 cd ~/Desktop
 ln -s ~/Library/Application\ Support/Blizzard/Diablo\ III/Screenshots
```

[Many thanks to William Voor over at Ask Different for this solution.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/51713/43)

Alternately, for those comfortable with leaving `~/Library` unhidden, you can open **Terminal.app**, (Located in `Applications/Utlities`, or easily found using Spotlight) and type or paste in the command:

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library/
```

At which point, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Additionally, hold downing the Option key in the "Go" Menu (in Finder) to will also show Library. After you have accessed ~/Library on a few times, it will start to appear in the "Recent Folders" submenu for easy repeat access. Even simpler, in Terminal, the command "open ~/Library/" will open Library in a new Finder window.

Answer (score 9):

They are in `[Your Username]/Library/Application Support/Blizzard/Diablo III/Screenshots`.

For all you Lion ppl, in addition to LessPop_MoreFizz's suggestions you can also access the Library in the following ways w/o making any changes to your computers setting:

- Hold downing the <kbd>Option</kbd> key in the "Go" menu in Finder
  will show you the Library. After you have accessed Library on a few times,
  it will start to appear in the "Recent Folders" submenu for easy
  repeat access.
- In Terminal, there is a simple command you can use to open Library in
  a new Finder window:  `open ~/Library/`

Comment: Putting them in a hidden-from-the-user-by-default folder is the most asinine thing...