# How do I remap the 'take screenshot' in Starcraft 2 when playing on keyboard without F13/PrintScreen?

Tags: starcraft-2

I have a MacBook, and I don't have an <kbd>F13</kbd> or <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key. How do I take a screenshot in StarCraft II? [This Q&A](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/how-do-i-take-a-screenshot-in-starcraft-2) didn't help me.

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/138721/192177

Comment: I'm playing on Mac OS not on Bootcamped Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On a Mac, you can take a screenshot in two different ways.

1. If you want to use Starcraft's in game screenshot functionality, remap the key with Iber's answer, then find the screenshot in `~/Library/Application Support/Blizzard/StarCraft II/Accounts/(SC2 account ID)/(some other folder)/Screenshots/`.  I don't know what the some other folder's name signifies, as I sourced that information from [this blog post](http://d43.me/blog/1265/where-does-starcraft-ii-save-screenshots-in-mac-os-x/) and he didn't know either.
2. You can also use OS X built in screen capture: <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> to save it as a png on your desktop. However **before** you must turn **on** Mac OS keyboard shortcuts in game options.

Answer (score 6):

In game you must go to **Options** > **Shortcuts** (H) > **Global** > **IU** > "**Make a screenshot**" and then change <kbd>F13</kbd> to the key of your choice.

Comment: However SC2 don't saves it to any folder. I double check Application Support as Blizzard suggests it. [Sarcasm On] Playing on Mac is such great adventure! [Sarcasm Off]

Comment: Did you check your individual users Application Support folder? This question may be useful: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66694/where-are-screenshots-stored-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Yup. I checked it 3 times. No screenshot folder.